# Using New-ADComputer's -ServicePrincipalNames

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I'm trying to use the `New-ADComputer` `-ServicePrincipalNames` parameter with no success.

```
$comp = New-ADComputer -passthru -name "server1" -path  "ou=Org2,ou=Org1,dc=mydomain,dc=com" -DNSHostName "server1.mydomain.com"  -serviceprincipalnames @{add="HOST\server1","HOST\server1.mydomain.com"}
```

but this results in this error:

```
New-ADComputer : The name reference is invalid
At line:1 char:10
+ $comp1 = New-ADComputer -name "server1" -path  "ou=Org2,ou=Org1,dc=mydomain,dc=com...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=server1,ou=Org2,ou=Org1,dc=mydomain,dc=com:String) [New-ADComputer], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The name reference is invalid,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADComputer
```

If I remove the `-serviceprincipalnames` parameter and use it like this:

```
$comp = New-ADComputer -passthru -name "server1" -path  "ou=Org2,ou=Org1,dc=mydomain,dc=com" -DNSHostName "server1.mydomain.com" 

$comp.serviceprincipalname.add("HOST\server1")
$comp.serviceprincipalname.add("HOST\server1.mydomain.com")

Set-ADComputer -Instance $comp
```

it works fine, but this results in a two step process.

I don't want to use the two step process (due to issues with multiple DCs and object replication) so am looking to figure out why this isn't working with the `New-ADComputer` command.

Comment: OK - now here's an indication that this is broken code on MS's part - I can use `-otherattributes @{serviceprincipalname="HOST/server1","HOST/server1.mydomain.com"}` in the `New-ADComputer` command and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into this same problem, and it seems like there is a bug in the way new-adcomputer adds UPN's to the serviceprincipalname field.
Most likely it's because it has to translate the backslashes to forward slashes, which it fails to do correctly when using the new-adcomputer.

However, if you use a piped set-adcomputer with forward slashed UPN's, it will correctly create your computer.

**Example of a working piped ServicePrincipalNames ad-computer creation.**

```
new-adcomputer -name 'test-pc01' -SAMAccountName 'test-pc01' -passthru -path "OU=TestComputers,OU=Domain,DC=Domain,DC=local" -DNSHostName 'test-pc01.domain.local' -enabled $true | Set-ADComputer -ServicePrincipalNames @{Add='HOST/test-pc01','TERMSRV/TEST-PC01'}
```

I'm not sure if it'll pass your multi step requirements, but it might help you find a solution.

Comment: Our problem is that the first connections (the new-adcomputer) sometimes hits a different DC then the second (the set-computer).  The second DC doesn't have the replicated object yet and we get a failure.  We can force a DC, but that's kind of ugly.